# Reading the WoWtRPG Ironforge Dwarf table

Tags: warcraft-tabletop-rpg

I found a table on World of Warcraft The RPG, which is the second edition for Warcraft The RPG.

[image]

I don't really get what the Fort save, Ref save, Will save mean, and are those 'Special' something like racial trait? And the actual "Ironforge Dwarf Level" 1st, 2nd and 3rd mean Character Level 1, 2 and 3?

Answer (score 9):

It’s a racial class progression. This is a concept from *Savage Species* that got used little in the rest of 3.5, but it’s a response to the various problems of playing “powerful” creatures.

Basically, under the usual rules, more powerful creatures are only playable with a “level adjustment” that says you “count” as however many levels higher for the purposes of XP. That means if you start playing at 3rd level, and you choose an LA +2 race, you only get 1 class level. If you start playing at 1st or 2nd level, the LA +2 race isn’t legal at all.

To get around these problems, *Savage Species* introduced the concept of creatures-as-classes. Basically, there were the stats of the base (“0th”-level) creature, and then there was a class progression for them. Those creatures were required to finish their creature-as-a-class before taking other class levels. So if you were starting at 1st level, instead of not being able to play an LA +2 creature, you instead played as a weaker version of that creature and you took levels in that creature’s class until you finished it. This allowed you to gradually accrue that creature’s racial benefits.

What the Warcraft RPG is doing here is saying that ironforge dwarves are more powerful than your typical race, so you can’t get all their benefits right away. Instead, you have to spend three levels getting them gradually. So your “class” for the first three levels is ironforge dwarf. After that, you can switch to a regular class, but you have to start from 1st in that class, so you’re behind a more normal creature of the same level (but you have your racial benefits, which are supposed to “make up” the difference).

In practice, this entire scheme doesn’t work very well. Better than the LA it replaced, but still, poorly. I recommend that people avoid it, particularly new players.

As for the table, that is the standard table describing what you get for taking levels in a class. If you have questions about *that*, I suggest you read the book more carefully and ask specific questions about what have you confused.

Comment: Having read the Warcraft RPG book, my (vaguely remembered) impression is that it's bad enough that reading it more closely might not clear up what a class table means, and the OP might be better off reading the D&D 3.5 PHB instead (since the WoWtRPG is almost entirely lifted from the 3.5 core rules).